# ListPlot3D: color function with blend

Tags: plotting, color

I have the following dataset:

```
test = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.25, 0.020}, {0, 0.5, 0.0045}, {0, 0.75, 
   0.0035}, {0, 1, 0.0025}, {0.25, 0, 0.10}, {0.25, 0.25, 
   0.0018}, {0.25, 0.5, 0.0035}, {0.25, 0.75, -0.015}, {0.25, 
   1, -0.02}, {0.5, 0, 0.15}, {0.5, 0.25, 0.015}, {0.5, 0.5, 
   0.00025}, {0.5, 0.75, -0.025}, {0.5, 1, -0.04}, {0.75, 0, 
   0.2}, {0.75, 0.25, 0.012}, {0.75, 0.5, 0.00015}, {0.75, 
   0.75, -0.035}, {0.75, 1, -0.06}, {1, 0, 0.25}, {1, 0.25, 
   0.007}, {1, 0.5, 0}, {1, 0.75, -0.045}, {1, 1, -0.09}}
```

The goal is to have a ListPlot3D of the {a,b,c} elements where:

- The maximum value of z is a pure red
- The minimum value of z is a pure green
- z=0 is depicted with a neutral color, like white or grey

I'm quite sure I need to use ColorFunction toghether with Blend, but I cannot make it work.

I can do it using discrete colors (red for positive and green for negative):

```
ListPlot3D[test, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, If[z >= 0, Red, Green]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

**OR** I can specify to use blend between red and green, without any control on the blending.

```
gradient[x_] := Blend[{Green, Red}, x]
ListPlot3D[test, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> (gradient[#3] &)]
```

Clearly I can find the max and the minimum value of z

```
max = Max[test[[All, 3]]]
min = Min[test[[All, 3]]]
```

But I cannot create the graph I want. Thanks for helping!

EDIT
This seems to work

```
ListPlot3D[test, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   If[z >= 0, Blend[{{0, Gray}, {max, Red}}, z], 
    Blend[{{min, Green}, {0, Gray}}, z]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

Comment: Note that `Blend` can take more than two colors, so `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{min, Green}, {0, White}, {max, Red}}, #3] &)` should do what you want

Comment: Lukas, I receive this message when implementing your code: ColorFunction->(Blend[{{min,Green},{0,White},{max,Red}},#3]&) is not \
a valid color function, or a gradient ColorData entity.

Comment: Can you post the exact code you were trying? Also, which version of Mathematica do you have?